# Editor for ClojureCLR

Tags: ide, editor, clojure, clojureclr

Is there an editor for ClojureCLR with REPL support and brace matching? I found a project which adds support for ClojureCLR to Visual Studio: [vsClojure](https://github.com/vsClojure/vsClojure), but couldn't build it. Are there any other options?

Comment: URL dead now. perhaps https://github.com/vsClojure/vsClojure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the readme.txt file:

Building:

```
1.) Install the Visual Studio 2010 SDK.
2.) Clone the vsClojure repository.
3.) Download the Managed Package Framework (http://mpfproj.codeplex.com/).
4.) Create a folder named "ManagedPackageFramework" in the solution directory.
5.) Copy the ManagedPackageFramework source to the new folder. 
6.) Open the vsClojure solution.
7.) Build
```

Running:

```
1.) Download or build ClojureCLR (http://github.com/richhickey/clojure-clr).
2.) Build vsClojure.
3.) Run vsClojure from Visual Studio.
4.) Add a new Clojure project.
5.) Set the path to ClojureCLR in the project properties.
```

Oh, and the readme also says:

```
In development - Not ready for use.
```

Comment: Yes, I did this. And after fixing a number of compilation errors I got the error: "Could not load referenced assembly ... Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Immutable.10.0.dll... This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded", which I didn't know how to fix. So i gave up.

Comment: vsClojure has been fixed now.